# How to force Plot.ly Python to use a given yaxis range?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

As you can see below, I manually define the range for each yaxis as well as setting the autorange option to be False.

However, if you graph this, you will still find the yaxis1 range is 0 to 20 rather than 0 to 25. As a result, one of the bars sticks out of the chart.

*How do I make it so that I can be certain every value will be contained within the yaxis range?*

**Edit:** Additionally, the top grid line in the second row is not showing. If I rescale slightly, it will appear again. So the issue seems to be purely graphical. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
from plotly import tools
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=['A', 'B'], shared_xaxes=False, shared_yaxes=True)

data = [[10, 4, 15, 20.5], [3, 12, 22.2], [6.5, 12, 26.2], [18, 4.2, 22.2]]
traces = [go.Bar(x=['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'], y=d) for d in data]

fig.append_trace(traces[0], 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(traces[1], 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(traces[2], 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(traces[3], 2, 2)

fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(title='', range=[0, 25], autorange=False)
fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(title='', range=[0, 30], autorange=False)

py.iplot(fig)
```

[image: Produced Chart with incorrect axis]

Comment: Is it possible that the y-axis actually goes to 25 but the value is not shown? If you add `dtick=5` to `yaxis1`, 25 should be visible as well.

Comment: This very well could be the case. However I am doing this as a part of a dashboard that will update in real time based on filters. And I can't see a very robust way to generate `dtick` values for a general chart. Thanks!

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I appologize, I seems I stole your answer, please do post your answer, I will delete mine, I had just skimmed the comments and noticed it wasn't answered, I didn't read your comment when I was working on the issue, sorry again!

Comment: @NarenMurali: No worries, that's fine. Your answer is way more detailed than my comment. Instead of deleting your answer, just add a reference.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Thanks, have added!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I tried your code and was able to replicate the issue.

**Reason:**

The cause for this, is that, if you look at the top left graph's yaxis you can see there are 3 values `[0, 10, 20]`, so there is a difference of `10`, between each of the values. so when you set the range as `[0, 25]`, the difference of `10` is not met, hence we not able to see `25` in the yaxis.

If we look at the graph on the bottom left's xaxis, we can see that the value `30` obeys the difference of `10`, between each of the values. Thus we are able to see `30` in the yaxis!

**Solution:**

If you look at the plotly documentation, found [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-dtick), we can use a particular property of the `yaxis` object to set the increment between each of the ticks, called `dtick`, plotly defines it as:

P.S: A personal Thank you to [Maximilian Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776376/maximilian-peters) for aiding to find the solution!!!!

> **dtick (number or categorical coordinate string)** 
>  Sets the step
>   in-between ticks on this axis. Use with `tick0`. Must be a positive
>   number, or special strings available to "log" and "date" axes. If the
>   axis `type` is "log", then ticks are set every 10^(n"dtick) where n is
>   the tick number. For example, to set a tick mark at 1, 10, 100, 1000,
>   ... set dtick to 1. To set tick marks at 1, 100, 10000, ... set dtick
>   to 2. To set tick marks at 1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, ... set dtick to
>   log_10(5), or 0.69897000433. "log" has several special values; "L",
>   where `f` is a positive number, gives ticks linearly spaced in value
>   (but not position). For example `tick0` = 0.1, `dtick` = "L0.5" will
>   put ticks at 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6 etc. To show powers of 10 plus small
>   digits between, use "D1" (all digits) or "D2" (only 2 and 5). `tick0`
>   is ignored for "D1" and "D2". If the axis `type` is "date", then you
>   must convert the time to milliseconds. For example, to set the
>   interval between ticks to one day, set `dtick` to 86400000.0. "date"
>   also has special values "M" gives ticks spaced by a number of
>   months. `n` must be a positive integer. To set ticks on the 15th of
>   every third month, set `tick0` to "2000-01-15" and `dtick` to "M3". To
>   set ticks every 4 years, set `dtick` to "M48"

So, when we set the `dtick` as `5` and the range as `[0,25]` we will get the expected result!

Please tryout the below code and let me know if your issue is resolved completely!

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()
from plotly import tools
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=['A', 'B'], shared_xaxes=False, shared_yaxes=True)

data = [[10, 4, 15, 20.5], [3, 12, 22.2], [6.5, 12, 26.2], [18, 4.2, 22.2]]
traces = [go.Bar(x=['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'], y=d) for d in data]

fig.append_trace(traces[0], 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(traces[1], 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(traces[2], 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(traces[3], 2, 2)

fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(title='', range=[0, 25], dtick=5, autorange=False)
fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(title='', range=[0, 30], autorange=False)

py_offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: I want to automate the generation of graphs and did not want to have to specify a tick value that would be a "nice" number. Instead wanted to give plotly a range that contains and have it do the work for me. But I do not think this is possible. Your method is what I ended up going with. Thanks!